# Python rolling mean starting on the next row

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have results from a horse race and want to have the rolling win count for the start of each race. This is what I currently have:

| Horse | Position |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 3 |

This is what I'm after

| Horse | Position | Wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 1 |

So when horse A started the second race it had 0 wins but when it started the third race is had 1 win

Answer (score 2):

Use the shift operator and cumsum

```
df["Wins"] = (df["Position"].shift(1) == 1).cumsum()
```

output:

```
  Horse  Position  Wins
0     A         4     0
1     A         1     0
2     A         3     1
```